# Discord.js how to know if user block the bot or not

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made code that let bot send user to private message, and I need to know if the user block the bot or failed to send him message.

This is what I tried. I don't want bot send message below if it fails:

> Message Sent!

[image]

```js
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix+'send')){
    if(!botOwner.includes(message.author.id)) return;
    let userID = 'ID'; //to send
    let channel = message.guild.channels.get(message.channel.id);
    let user = bot.users.get(userID);
    let myMessage = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
    if(!myMessage) return;


    user.send(myMessage)
    .then(channel.send('Message Sent!')) //The problem in this line <-
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
        message.channel.send(`**${user.username}**, Failed to send him ❌`)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a *function* into [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

```js
// Keep in mind that 'user' is a GuildMember the way it's been defined, not a User.

user.send(myMessage)
  .then(() => message.channel.send(':incoming_envelope: Message sent successfully!'))
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(`Error while sending message to ${user.displayName}...\n`, err);

    message.channel.send(':x: Message could not be sent.')
      .catch(err => console.error(`Error while sending error message...\n`, err));
  });
```

Answer (score -3):

I would do it like this:

```
var error = false;

user.send(myMessage)
 .catch(err => {

  error = true;

  console.error(err)
  message.channel.send(`**${user.displayName}**, Failed to send message. ❌`)

 });

if (!error) channel.send('Message Sent!')
```

Comment: There is problem with `if (!error)`

When i block the bot it show me `Message Sent` and error message..
When i do `if (error)` don't show me `Message Sent`. Can you try it.

Comment: I can't test it right know but maybe you are putting the `if (!error)` into `.then()` **after** `.catch()`.